# Android c2dm registration failed

Tags: android, registration, android-c2dm

How many days does C2DM take to activate the registration ? I've received an email indicating that it'll take a day or so, but I keep getting an "authentication failed" when I try to register a device.

I'm absolutely sure I didn't make any mistakes in the code, configuration or sender email.

Comment: problem solved: the problem was that the service requires an existing connection for Google ( gmail )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, from the moment you received your email it should take 1, maximum 2 days (I didn't hear of cases in which it took longer). If more than 2 days passed, the problem is probably because of you, and not the Google servers.

Google specifically explains what `AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` means: 
[Take a look here.](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#handling_reg) Make sure you are using the proper credentials.

FYI, avoid saying that you are 100% positive about your code, and post meaningful code snippets, just in case.

Comment: thanks for your answer , it was because "It uses an existing connection for Google services. This requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices." so if user is not connected with gmail account , that error occurred ( sorry for the code anyway )